# Marketing Cloud Journey missing email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

We are using MC Journeys to send some stuff out to clients. But we seem to be missing 280 emails sends and i can't find where this has happened.

We have used serval journey's and journey version to implement this send, So screenshots don't show the full picture.

Across each upload there was 9283 contacts to be emailed,
From this there was 126 contacts added to an exclusion list

When the journey was sent out we only got 8877 emails going out. Thats 406 emails (including the exclusion list).

I have checked the MC Global lists and the missing items are not in there. There was also no duplicates within the CSV.

What are the possible items that could course this loss of email sends?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many different reasons why some emails were not delivered.

- First of all, to start troubleshooting you can check what [status is shown inside the Journey's Email Activity itself](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_view_email_activity_statistics.htm&type=5).
- Then you can check several subscribers' status in the All Subscribers list just to get a confirmation whether they are eligible even to get an email.
- Additionally, you can check [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5), especially [_Bounced](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5) one.
- The best option though - is always to perform [Tracking Data Extract with NotSent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382076&type=1) data which should give you a reason why some subscribers have not received an email.